# Problem connecting to the database with RedBean php

Tags: php, mysql, database, redbean

I use open server with RedBean PHP. After connecting to the database, when I try to create a table, I have an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'Could not connect to database (sots).' 
in C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php:1011 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(735): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->connect() 
#1 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(1035): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('show tables', Array) 
#2 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(1056): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll('show tables', Array) 
#3 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(4183): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetCol('show tables', Array) 
#4 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(6652): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->getCol('show tables') 
#5 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(5857): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\MySQL->getTables() 
#6 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(8912): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->tableExists('acounts') 
#7 C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php(9014): Re in C:\Users\george\OSPanel\domains\divinehunt.com\rb.php on line 1011
```

in this script I connect redbean and to the database:

```
<?php
require "rb.php";   

R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sots',
        'mysql ', 'mysql' );
 ?>
```

when you click on the button from the form it is executed:

```
<?php session_start(); require_once "db.php";
> 
> $data=$_POST; if (isset($data['do_regis'])) {
>     $user= R::dispense('acounts');
>     $user->login=$data['login'];
>     R::store($user);
>     $dir=$data['login'];
>     if (is_dir($dir)==false) {
>       mkdir('Accounts/'.$dir);
>       mkdir('Accounts/'.$dir.'/Postes');
>       mkdir('Accounts/'.$dir.'/Photos');
>     }
> 
> }
> ?>
```

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue?